# jQuery - Remove selected option from parent list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have list 1:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" selected>VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

And list 2:

```
<select>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
</select>
```

I want to use jQuery to remove from list2 the list1's selected value(s). Can be one or more values.

I'm using this code to add options from list 1 to list 2:

```
var options = $("#list1 option:selected").clone();
$("#list2 select").append(options);
```

Comment: What would happen if you deselect some items in list1? Is there any function which initializes the items in list2 when first loaded?

Comment: Your code does the opposite. The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Vohuman it was an example of add items. But i want to remove them.

Comment: @humble.rumble yes, that's what i want.

Comment: @humble.rumble i don't use more javascript to add items selected on list 1. I just want a function to remove all list1's selected items from list2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple select element ("Can be one or more values"), the `val` method returns an array of selected values. You can use that array for filtering the corresponding option elements:

```
var vals = $('#list1 select').val();

$('#list2 option').filter(function() {
   return vals.indexOf(this.value) > -1;
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove option in list2  chosen from list1

```
$('#list1').on('change',function(){
    var thisval = $(this).val();
        $("#list2 option[value='"+thisval+"']").remove();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dge8nu6n/)

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the logic into two distinct functions:

1. Remove options based on a list of possible values
2. Get selected values from a select box

Depending on whether you've specified `multiple` attribute in the select box, the selected value will either be an array or a single value.

```js
function remove_options(select, values)
{
  $('> option', select).filter(function() {
    return values.indexOf(this.value) != -1;
  }).remove();
}

function selected_values(select)
{
  var values = $(select).val();

  return $.isArray(values) ? values : [values];
}

remove_options('#list2', selected_values('#list1'));
remove_options('#list2_multiple', selected_values('#list1_multiple'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" selected>VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="list2">
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" selected>VW</option>
</select>

<select id="list1_multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" selected>VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="list2_multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" selected>VW</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
function removeOption (i) {
    $("#list2 select > option:eq("+i+")").remove();
}
removeOption(2);
```

if you want to remove the 3rd option.

Comment: This is a "static" solution = worst solution. And i can't confirm if it works.